# Hiding & Unhiding Excel Rows

Tags: excel, vba

Here are my requirements:

The user will select 1 - 10 in a drop down list, which unhides up to 10 groups of rows below this. Let's call each group to be hidden/shown "X", and X consists of about 13 rows, and there are 10 X's stacked vertically on the sheet. Therefore, when a user selects '2' for example it will reveal the first two X's, but the remaining 8 groups of rows remain hidden. This part of the code works fine, but it is the background.

Here is the not-working part. Within each "X" (group of rows now made visible based on previous input), the user enters info down the page, and as they go down I would like certain rows within individual X's to hide/unhide based on inputs.

For example, if the user inputs "Residential status" as "Renting", a row should be unhidden saying "Input weekly rent here." Or if they input it as "Other" a different row should be unhidden saying "Please comment."

Hope this clarifies,

This is my current code for just the first 'X', I figured I'd fix this part first then replicate it:

```
If Cells(3, 55).Value = "1" Then
    Rows("57:70").EntireRow.Hidden = False 'User selects options 1- 10
    If (Range(C62) = "Renting" Or Range(C62) = "Paying Off Home - Mortgaged To OFI") Then
        Rows("63").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf (Range(C62) = "" Or Range(C62) = "*") Then
        Rows("63:64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range(C62) = "Other" Then
        Rows("63").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("64").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End If
```

Comment: use `Cells(3, 55).Value = 1`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you talk about this `X` that the user is picking? They're supposed to select options 1-10 but you're only showing us 3 of the scenarios you have so far. Does this code work as is and you want to add something to it?

Comment: Yeah it (sort of) works but doesn't do everything desired. Only showing one example for clarity. 
In this case, I would say "X" is rows 57:70 (line 2).
Code doesn't work around the part where it is hiding/unhiding the same rows that have been hidden/unhidden previously